# parse_ini_file like php.ini

Tags: php, arrays, ini

I noticed that if I have like

```
thing = abc
thing = def
thing = xyz
```

I get only one thing entry in the array.

But php.ini has multiple declaration of "extension", which I assume gets them all as an array.

Can parse_ini_file do the same? The INI_SCANNER_RAW option doesn't seem to change this.

Comment: Alex the php.ini file is parsed by PHP itself, as you can see here: http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/main/php_ini.c?view=markup. It doesn't use PHP to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have an array of `thing`, you'll need to change your declarations to `thing[]`. From the docs:

```
; This is a sample configuration file
; Comments start with ';', as in php.ini

[first_section]
one = 1
five = 5
animal = BIRD

[second_section]
path = "/usr/local/bin"
URL = "http://www.example.com/~username"

[third_section]
phpversion[] = "5.0"
phpversion[] = "5.1"
phpversion[] = "5.2"
phpversion[] = "5.3"
```

Would result in

```
Array
(
    [one] => 1
    [five] => 5
    [animal] => Dodo bird
    [path] => /usr/local/bin
    [URL] => http://www.example.com/~username
    [phpversion] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5.0
            [1] => 5.1
            [2] => 5.2
            [3] => 5.3
        )

)
Array
(
    [first_section] => Array
        (
            [one] => 1
            [five] => 5
            [animal] => Dodo bird
        )

    [second_section] => Array
        (
            [path] => /usr/local/bin
            [URL] => http://www.example.com/~username
        )

    [third_section] => Array
        (
            [phpversion] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5.0
                    [1] => 5.1
                    [2] => 5.2
                    [3] => 5.3
                )

        )

)
```